# Windows Startup folder environment variable

Tags: windows, boot, environment-variables

I'm developing a setup.exe for my application that copies it to the startup folder with the following path:

```
cd %PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Now I'm worried if this path could change in different versions of Windows. Does anybody knows if the startup folder path is always the same? There is a better way to configure an application to start every boot?

Any tip will be very helpful,

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The startup priority in Windows is as follows, listed from first to start to last to start:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Runonce
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
SystemDrive\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
SystemDrive\Documents and Settings\username\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

The last two items relate to Windows XP days. Which relate to    `%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

And yes, to answer your question, Windows Vista, 7, 8, and 10 use the same startup folder.

So, if you want your program to run first, always use: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Otherwise, the startup folder, will load after everything else is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look up the folders from the shell namespace, e.g. by passing [`FOLDERID_Startup`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/knownfolderid) (or `FOLDERID_CommonStartup`) to the functions to lookup folder from the [shell namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath).

The registry entries (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run and others) mentioned in another answer are better options. See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SetupApi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys)

Microsoft also has an [article describing the relative order of the different methods](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/179365/info-run-runonce-runservices-runservicesonce-and-startup).

(The startup folder has the advantage of being easy(ish) for the user to control)